# Ruby Building an Array

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

Argh. Having trouble here trying to work out how to build my array in Ruby.

So I am looping through a result and I want to add the category field as the key and have it so that if the next row has the same category it gets put into that category. If not, it makes a new array and adds it to that.

Here is what I have so far.

```
data = Array.new
results.each do |row|
   data[row.category].push row.field
end
```

Which is not going to work I know. I want `data[row.category]` to eventually be (after the loop) an array containing all the `row.field`'s

So I end up with an array that looks like this.

```
[['Dogs', 5, 12, 2], ['Cats', 4, 5, 9], ['Fish', 25, 82, 23]]
```

So no matter how many loops I do, if I push it into an array that already exists in data then it just appends it, if the array doesn't exist it creates it and then appends it.

In PHP I would simply do this:

```
$data[$row['category']][] = $row['field']
```

With the empty [] denoting to create a new array if there is none. How do I do this in Ruby???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you seem to be confused by PHP and its associative arrays (which aren't called arrays in any other language :) ). You need a hash. Try this snippet:

```
data = results.each_with_object({}) do |row, memo|
  memo[row.category] ||= []  # create array unless it exists
  memo[row.category] << row.field
end
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your quick reply however with this result: `{"category"=>"Sales", "field"=>5502.0}` I am getting this error with the code sample: `undefined method 'category' for #<Hash:0x007f84fb44e5d0>` Any ideas?

Comment: @SolidPink: yep, just use `row['category']` instead of `row.category`.

Comment: Bingo! Thanks for that. So why row[''] instead of row. ?

Comment: Because, unlike PHP, ruby doesn't do weird mumbo-jumbo behind the scenes. Hash is a simple structure. It doesn't have a `category` method. But it does have a `[]` method that gets you a value by its key. :)

Comment: Also, just quickly. How do I start a new hash with a certain length. For example with the above code, there might be some `data[row.category]` with 2 entries and some with 3. (or whatever, the point being that its not going to be a nice, neat hash). Can I pad it out? Maybe say somehow missing values are nil?

Comment: Cause my results can be `[[500,400,300], [650,300]]` so I would love it to pad it out to say `[[500,400,300], [650,300,0]]` or nil instead of 0

Comment: Missing array elements are nil by default. You don't have to do anything.

Comment: Not when you want to use it in HTML or javascript. The complete arrays are successful but Javascript crashes with an incomplete array.

Comment: @SolidPink: ah. Well, that's another question. First try to solve it yourself.

Comment: Hmm not sure. Im trying to set the default but its removing everything.

Comment: Is there a padding method for hashes that I am not aware of or that isn't in the docs?

Comment: Would you be able to let me know if you do? I've been researching for hours and can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike PHP, you cannot use any object as index for an [`Array`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html). In Ruby, we use [`Hash`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html)es to associate arbitrary objects with other objects.

Your code should work if you change it to:

```
data = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }

results.each do |row|
   data[row.category] << row.field
end
```

Comment: No, this won't cover the creation of new array.

Comment: Did you test this version of code? I sense that it still won't work.

Comment: results is whatever you wish to loop over. Could be an object. In my case, its a result from a DB query.